# What is the optimum method of finding the per-item earliest date from a clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

I have a SQL Server 2012 table which contains columns like this:

```
ID int NOT NULL,
EventDate datetime NOT NULL,
... 32 other columns...
```

where the table has about half a billion rows across a range of about 10000 distinct ID values.

The table has a unique clustered index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [MyIndex] ON [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [ID] ASC,
    [EventDate] ASC
)
```

I need to find the earliest per-ID EventDate, which I can obtain using a query such as:

```
SELECT ID, min(EventDate) FROM [dbo].[MyTable] GROUP BY ID
```

However this query takes just under 2 minutes to complete.

I can't share the specifics (query plans etc.) of the problem I'm looking at due to NDA constraints, but I can advise that I'm seeing a clustered index scan, so it's checking all the rows in the table. Given that the data is organised in EventDate sequence I'd expect that the retrieval could be much quicker, but I'm not sure quite how. Any other ID specific range query responds in a few milliseconds and the table has recently been rebuilt and reindexed, so I don't think there are any statistic updates which would help.

Can anyone suggest a better method of determining the minimum per-ID EventDate value which avoids scanning the entire clustered index?

I do have a table with the (10 thousand) distinct `id` values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is related to **"Index Skip Scan"** optimization (see the [Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan) below, from 2011). Unfortunately it has been closed as **"Won't Fix"**.

Some related enhancements are already there but only for partitioned tables: [Query Processing Enhancements on Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345599(SQL.105).aspx).

Various workarounds exist though:

---

**Workaround / solution 1: `CROSS APPLY` to subquery with `TOP 1`**

If there is a table with the (10K) distinct `ID` values, we can use it to do a `CROSS APPLY`.

```
-- if you don't have a table already
CREATE TABLE MyTableIDs
  ( ID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ) ;

-- we only do this once
INSERT INTO MyTableIDs (ID)
SELECT ID 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID ;
```

Then the query will do (10K) seeks into the index:

```
SELECT  i.ID, a.EventDate
FROM    MyTableIDs AS i
    CROSS APPLY
        ( SELECT TOP (1) t.EventDate
          FROM     MyTable AS t
          WHERE    t.ID = i.ID
          ORDER BY EventDate
        ) AS a ;
```

---

**Workaround / solution 2: Implement "Skip Scan" with Recursive CTE**

Another option is a recursive CTE to implement the skip scan. Here is a demo script, posted by @PaulWhite on SSC in October 2010, demonstrating how much faster an rCTE can be: [Calculating interest query](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/873124/Calculating-interest-query?PageIndex=5#bm1013407)

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
WITH    RecursiveCTE
AS      (
        SELECT  a.*
        FROM    ( SELECT TOP (1)  ID, EventDate
                  FROM     MyTable
                  ORDER BY ID, EventDATE
                ) AS a
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  r.ID, r.EventDate
        FROM    (
                -- A cunning way to use TOP in the recursive part of a CTE ;)
                SELECT  t.ID, t.EventDate,
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.EventDate)
                FROM    MyTable AS t
                JOIN    RecursiveCTE AS r
                        ON  r.ID < t.ID
                ) AS r
        WHERE   r.rn = 1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    RecursiveCTE
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0) ;
```

---

**Workaround / solution 3: Partitioned Table**

Available if you have Enterprise edition. More details about this possibility in the linked article: [Query Processing Enhancements on Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345599(SQL.105).aspx)

The main disadvantage is that the skip scan will work only if `ID` is the partitioning column.

---

**Workaround / solution 4: Additional Index**

Adding an NCI index on `(ID, EventDate)` allows an index scan on the much smaller index. See [@Daniel Hutmacher's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176246/what-is-the-optimum-method-of-finding-the-per-item-earliest-date-from-a-clustere/176247#176247) for an explanation.

It's still a scan though and not (many) seeks so I'm not sure if it will scale as good as options 1 and 2. Of course everything depends on details (column sizes, number of distinct IDs vs number of repeated values, etc).

---

**<strike>Workaround / solution</strike> (no, not working) 5: Indexed View**

Nice idea, if it worked. Unfortunately a view cannot be indexed if it has `GROUP BY` and `MIN/MAX`, see restrictions of [Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views).

I wonder why, since it is allowed (and be indexed) if it has `GROUP BY` and `COUNT_BIG()`. There may be a Connect item about it, too!

---

**Workaround / solution 6: "Do It Yourself" Indexed View**

Implement an equivalent to an indexed view yourself. You could for example, add a `MinEventDate` column in `MyTableIDs` (the table with the distinct `ID` values, see option 1) and add triggers in `MyTable` that update this column accordingly. Then your query would be a simple `SELECT` from `MyTableIDs`.

---

**Links to related web pages**

- Connect item: [Implement Index Skip Scan](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan)
- Implemented feature: [Query Processing Enhancements on Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345599(SQL.105).aspx)
- Indexed Views and restrictions: [Create Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views)

Comment: Yes, thats the ticket - thanks! The first suggestion is nicely simple and runs in less than a second, so suits my needs nicely. The RecursiveCTE solution is rather scary looking for a (relatively) simple query and I so haven't tried it out as yet...

Answer (score 5):

You could try adding a *non-clustered* index with the same definition, that would make the index considerably smaller in size (particularly if your table is wide).

You won't eliminate the scan, but it would be much faster.

Clustered indexes contain the entire table's data, whereas non-clustered ones only store the specific columns that you define (as well as a pointer to the clustering key or row ID, but in your case those would already be in the index key).

Comment: Kindly correct my understanding. I have read that clustered index only contains that column's data as contradictory to your statement.

Comment: It's the other way around, at least for SQL Server. "Clustered", in this sense, means "interleaved".

Comment: @Daniel Hutmacher - I considered this, but can't help feeling that better-use of the existing clustered index, assuming it's possible, is far preferable. I can't justify adding a new index to support this query alone.

Comment: @Elliveny then you're basically left with looking at more memory or faster storage imo. :)

Comment: @DanielHutmacher : thanks for clearing concept. Appreciate!

Comment: @Daniel Hutmacher - Yes, that would help but it is a sledgehammer approach to the problem! Given SQL Server is able to get to the data for each ID very quickly then, to my way of thinking, it is almost there. I simply need the first row in the clustered index for each distinct ID, which is something around 10000 reads rather than half a billion... I can't help but think there must be a way to acheive it!